# Ubuntu 12.04 install error: ubi-partman failed with exit code 141

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, boot-repair

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my preinstalled windows 7 Sony vaio s series laptop
following instructions here:
http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/

Everything went well and I am able to boot in to windows after complete installation of Ubuntu. Now following instructions on web I tried to add Ubuntu to my BIOS using Easy BCD (but forget to add windows 7 entry).
As a result, I loose windows 7 OS and can't boot in to either OS 
then I successfully repaired windows 7 using recovery CD.

**Now my problem is that I can't reinstall Ubuntu 12.04 using Live CD it halts every time before disk partition step giving error.**

"ubi-partman crashed". "ubi-partman failed with exit code 141. further information may be found in /var/log/syslog. Do you want to try running this step again before continuing? If you do not, your installation may fail entirely or may be broken."

and, any choice to continue will result in the same error.

I looked in to /var/log/syslog but not able to understand what is error.

Then, I ran sudo fdisk -l to view my partitions and it shows me only one partition. Probably, all the partitions I created for Ubuntu 12.04 are lost while running windows 7 recovery CD. 
 So, I don't know whether the Ubuntu is still there or probably corrupted.

My boot-info URL is:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1202146/

Please tell me how to remove this error so that I can reinstall/repair Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks in advance.
R Shukla

---

My boot-info URL is:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1202146/

Please tell me how to remove this error so that I can reinstall/repair Ubuntu 12.04

---

Thanks for your help!
I tried to boot from the CD but I every time it give me error before disk partitioning step. Also, I am unable to start Gparted.

**"ubi-partman crashed". "ubi-partman failed with exit code 141. further information may be found in /var/log/syslog. Do you want to try running this step again before continuing? If you do not, your installation may fail entirely or may be broken."**

and, any choice to continue will result in the same error.

I looked in to  /var/log/syslog but not able to understand what is error.

Then, I ran 
sudo fdisk -l to view my partitions and it shows me only ne partition.
Probaply, all the partitions I created for Ubuntu 12.04 are lost while running windows 7 recovery CD.
Please tell me how to remove this error.

Best Regards,
R S

Comment: @Rini - if you register your account it will make it easier for you to look after and edit your own question.  The section below is for answers.  Please do not add an answer unless it really is an answer to your own question. Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar error, and it only relented after I changed the flag for the primary partition to "boot". My disk was clobbered by a bad driver for a USB 3.0 card I attempted to install, so I suspect that the flag was corrupted.

Comment: Duplicate of [ubi-partman failed with exit code 141](http://askubuntu.com/questions/277925/ubi-partman-failed-with-exit-code-141)

Comment: [Bug #945027 - ubi-partman failed with exit code 141](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/945027)

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is boot into the live CD. If you have gparted on it (which I think it is) then open that and try to find out the size or other details of your two partitons. With this information it should be possible to identify your win and your Linux partition.

Then reformat the ubuntu partitons. You should be able to use gparted for that. But you will need to umount them (you can do that in gparted as well).

After that it should be possible for you to reinstall again.

Good luck!