# Ubi-partman failed with exit code 141 from usb install

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gnome

I am in the process of installing Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 from a USB ISO onto my laptop that I want to dual boot with Windows 10. I got to the step for creating a partition and was allocating about 50 GB; however, ubi-partman crashed with the 141 exit code. I clicked try again, but there hasn't been any progress for an hour and it seems to be stuck in that same error notification.

What can I do at this point?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Similar reports from earlier LTS installs without resolution, it seems.  People seem to think it's related to an existing partition scheme, and possibly the presence of already installed OSes...  e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/186738/ubuntu-12-04-install-error-ubi-partman-failed-with-exit-code-141?rq=1

Comment: Depending on what you click in the interface, it seems this problem can also manifest as an installer crash with the "internal problem" dialog, generating a report related to ubiquity

Comment: I fix my problem with this solution:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1222814/881609

Answer (score 6):

[Ubi-partman failed with exit code 141 from usb install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817344/ubi-partman-failed-with-exit-code-141-from-usb-install)

I run into similar ubi-partman crash 141 exit code. Though I could not find any easy solution. Though, my platform is desktop Dell OptiPlex 7040, SSD TOSHIBA NVMe THNSN5512GPU7 (18 RAM, CPU i7-6700); I wanted to install Kubuntu 18.04 LTS, and after successfully booting from USB flash I stopped on ubi-partman crash 141 exit code in installation process (you cannot go to partition/disk settings).

I tried disable Fastboot on Windows 10 (yes I wanted dual boot) but just this did not work.

(see for example:)
https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10

I also noticed in BIOS settings, there is RAID ON. I actually do not know what it means, but if I changed it to ASCI:

[image]

https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci

Error 141 disapeared and I was able to install Kubuntu. (so SATA was set to AHCI and Fastboot on Windows was disabled)

It is worth to backup Windows, though I did not do it, because system was clean. Switch operation is not without risk - I read it is possible you will not be able to boot your Windows - though I had no problem.

Before my solution you can go through this general help UEFI install.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147295

Comment: same issue with kubuntu 20, change to SATA AHCI resolved the error, actually I detected with Raid ON the hard disk was not visible to kubuntu at all

Comment: Excellent answer. Ubuntu wouldn't even detect the disk in Raid mode. What is this option about anyway, there's no raid in the system ?!?

Answer (score 4):

Allocate an ext4 partition using your free space in your live session gParted before starting the installation process. This solved the same issue for me.

Comment: **This** solved that error. Easy, and no need to erase anything else. Basically, reformat the partition that will receive Ubuntu, as ext4 (via gparted, or use `mkfs.ext4 /dev/partition_number` if you have access to another Linux box). Be careful to reformat the right one!

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and tried for hours to get past that point in the installer, but couldn't until I decided to **wipe the drive**.  To save your windows product key, you may use [produkey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) within windows.  Then you can later reinstall windows from [official install media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10ISO) if you wish. Hopefully you already backed up your data at the start of this process. If not, [do it now!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc/586172#586172) This process will erase all data currently on the drive.

Then, from your Ubuntu USB ISO:

1. open GParted
2. choose Device > create partition table, choose msdos type
3. retry the Ubuntu installer, and it should now proceed past the error

Comment: Wiping the drive seems an extreme approach. Not one that i would recommend lightly, especially without recommending [backup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc/586172#586172)

Comment: @ElderGeek A problem with your partition scheme is very serious; wiping the drive is a solution on par with that problem. As I noted in the comments above, this solution was not recommended lightly. I investigated other avenues for solutions first.

Comment: You have my apologies if I misunderstood. I cannot find the comment you speak of, nor the part of your answer where you seem to consider loss of data at all.

Comment: @ElderGeek Comments are under the original question above. Maybe they're only visible to me? Anyway, you're right that it can't hurt to give one more warning to back up their data -- I made the edit. I can't imagine someone editing their drive partitions without having a backup, then wiping the drive and not realizing they would lose data as a result.  Then again, many things happen that I couldn't imagine...

Comment: Good edit. Over time I've realized the unimaginable happens with it seems unceasing regularity. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exit code 10, then launched the live Ubuntu 18.04 with the nodmraid option.

After that I had ubi-partman exit code 141, ubi-timezone exit code 1 and the installer would freeze most of the time.

I created a swap partition with 4GB and the installer gave no more errors. I still ran the installer with the nodmraid option.