# Can't install Xubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu

I've bought a new computer that comes without an OS and I have been unsuccessfully trying to install a Ubuntu variant there for a few days now. I've tried Mint and had many issues with it (see https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2393303) and so decided to install Xubuntu on a USB drive and try to install from there, figured there would be more help for Xubuntu than Mint.

Now I have the USB with a bootable Xubuntu, and I'm trying to install it to the computer.

I sometimes boot into Xubuntu (Try Xubuntu without Installing option) and everything seems fine, but sometimes I boot and whenever I try to run an application I get this error:´

**Failed to execute default Terminal Emulator**
                Input/output error.

And the only option I have is close. That error isn't just for the terminal, for example when I try to run the browser it says

**Failed to execute default Web Browser.**
Failed to execute child process "/usr/bin/firefox"(Input/output error).

and so on and so forth, I can't even log out from the GUI because I get that error. However, if I do ALT+F4 it works to reach the log out menu, and the computer shuts down fine.

Other times though, I turn on the computer and boot into the USB and everything works fine without giving me that error in any application. I have no idea why, it seems to be random because I do everything exactly the same and sometimes everything works and other times nothing works.

When I first tried to install stuff, using the Install Xubuntu boot option, it gave me the error ubi-partman failed with exit code 141. I solved that error by formatting the ssd where I'm trying to install the OS following the second answer here: [Ubi-partman failed with exit code 141 from usb install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817344/ubi-partman-failed-with-exit-code-141-from-usb-install)

However, after I formatted the drive and ran the installer the installer abruptly stopped in the second to last menu. No error, no warning, it just stops working when I hit Continue and doesn't install anything.

Now the last time I tried to run the installer it failed when I hit continue in the Updates and other software menu, with "ubi-partman failed with exit code 2". I quit the installation, tried again but got the same error so I rebooted and booted again into Try Xubuntu Without Installing. (on this time with the new ubi-partman crash, the browser opened fine, but the terminal and the log out button gave me the input/output error, first time I noticed it working for some apps and not for others).

Now, after rebooting all the applications worked fine. I tried running the installer, and it didn't give me that error (even though I did everything the same). I get to the Erase Disk and Install Xubuntu menu, select the SSD and press install now, and as usual the installer just crashed without errors or anything. I shut down the computer (the apps still run fine after the installer crash by the way), and I boot into Install Xubuntu. In the Updates and other software menu, I pressed continue and it waited a couple minutes and then ubi-partman failed with exit code 141.

I have no idea what to do, I've tried installing with 3 different ISOs, nothing works, and it always fails in different manners.

This was all done with the BIOS set to Legacy Boot.

I just tried setting it to UEFI and then booting into Try Xubuntu Without Installing. It crashed again with no error in that same menu, the only difference was that it asked me to disable secure boot and for a password for booting in the install third party drivers menu. I then shut down the computer, boot into Try Xubuntu Without Installing and got the ubi-partman failed with exit code 2 error,

I'm absolutely lost.

Edit: Tried booting with nomodeset option and I was able to proceed past that screen! I got an error in another screen, saying something about an error with partitions. I rebooted the computer with that option but was unable to get past that screen, the installer crashed again. There were changes to the SSD, it was encrypted (I'm installing with full disk encryption). I reformatted the drive to ntfs, like it was when I was able to get past that screen, but I haven't been able to get past that screen again. I have no idea why I got further in that try, it was the first time I tried nomodeset but in all the other times I have tried with that option I wasn't able to replicate what happened. I'm getting more and more lost, because I always get different errors and then am unable to replicate them when I want, even though I do everything the same.

Comment: did you try the same usb stick with another computer, trying to know where the problem come from

Comment: @cmak.fr what do you mean? Try to install from the USB in another computer? No, I don't have a spare computer to install a OS there. Or do you mean just try Xubuntu without Installing? I can do that, but I haven't. I figure the problem is with the computer, because I tried different ISOs and distros and they all failed, and I have installed Linux before on many computers with many distros and I never got these many errors.

Comment: I/O errors are usually from bad disks. You can try with a new USB drive. You can also run `memtest86+`.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex you are indeed correct.

Comment: If you want, please add the solution that worked for you to the answers section below, then wait a few hours or a day and click the grey checkmark to the left of your answer to mark the question solved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the USB drive I was using, it was broken. I tried with another one and it worked the first time.