# "ubi-partman failed with code 141" error during installation on an Asus Zenbook, dualboot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, kubuntu, asus

tl;dr: "ubi-partman failed with code 141" error on an Asus Zenbook, fresh install on a bootable USB drive, dual boot with Win10.

Hey all.

First time trying a non-mac/windows computer; attempting to install Kubuntu (edit: 20.04.3 LTS) on a fairly recent Asus Zenbook purchased three months ago, and to dual-boot it with Win10 while I'm testing it out and making sure my drawing programs work on it. Please be patient with me as I'm reasonably okay with google-fu (otherwise I wouldn't be here) and played with wine a decade ago, but anything linux is brand news for me.

Pre-Install Details:

- I'm mostly following this video tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhPBRfAHZSg) along with this as a backup (https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/)
- I download the latest stable kubuntu iso, and rufus for the USB drive. installation on the USB drive seems to go through with no problem as per the instructions in the video tutorial.
- I go into Disk Management for partitioning my drive, and run into a minor problem; I don't have a free drive other than "C". I tell Disk Management to shrink C drive (by 80GB; I have 1TB on the laptop so I still have plenty of space for Windows).
- I thankfully stumble on something (https://errorcodespro.com/asus-boot-from-usb/) that mentioned Asus Zenbooks need to have Fast Boot DISABLED and Secure Boot Control DISABLED. I go into BIOS and I turn off those two using the steps in the linked tutorial, but cannot find "Next, you’ll enable [Launch CSM]. (Compatibility Support Module)" I ignore this for the time being? (maybe this is part of the problem?)

Install:

- I reboot the laptop ... hold down the ESC key as per the Asus-specific instructions to get into the boot menu ... it does some things quickly enough I can't tell what it does, but Kubuntu's logo pops up ... I get to the point where I see the colorful desktop ... it starts the install from install-to-USB (as I don't hit the "try" button), I get to choose the language, keyboard settings, no problem up to the point it goes into the "software" panel.
- and then I immediately get the "ubi-partman failed with code 141" error.

Help?

The only thing I can see remotely close to my use-case is this question ([Can't Install Kubuntu on my New Asus Vivo Book Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098322/cant-install-kubuntu-on-my-new-asus-vivo-book-pro/1222814#1222814)) "After many hours of research, I find a solution that is changing SATA configuration in BIOS to AHCI from Intel RST." I have no idea what those words mean.

another answer here ([Ubi-partman failed with exit code 141 from usb install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817344/ubi-partman-failed-with-exit-code-141-from-usb-install)) says "Allocate an ext4 partition using your free space in your live session gParted before starting the installation process. This solved the same issue for me." but I literally have no idea what any of those words mean or the specific steps needed there.